# vue3 @change doesn't work(code brought to vue2 project)

Tags: vuejs3

I brought the vue2 code to the vue3 project. All other functions run, but @change="onPageChanged" does not run. I don't know the reason. Help me.

i'm sorry about my poor english. sorry
i installed bootstrap and bootstrap-vue-3. other methods are working but only @change didn't work. is this because of vue version is changed?

```
  <div class="overflow-auto">


    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <b-row :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage"> 
      <b-card-group class ="col-4" v-for="(item,idx) in paginatedItems" :key="idx" >
        <b-card class="mb-5" :title="item.first_name" :img-src="item.imgurl" img-alt="Image" img-top>
          <b-card-text>
            {{item.last_name}}
          </b-card-text>
          <template #footer>
            <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
          </template>
        </b-card>
      
      </b-card-group>
    </b-row>
    <b-pagination
      align="center"
      @click="asd"
      @change="onPageChanged"
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="totalRows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
    ></b-pagination>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const items = [
          { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg' },
          { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  },
          { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople', imgurl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817_960_720.jpg'  }
        ]
export default {
  name : 'Pagination',
    data() {
      return {
        items : items,
        paginatedItems: items,
        totalRows: items.length,
        perPage: 3,
        currentPage: 1,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      asd () {
        console.log(123)
      },
      paginate (page_size, page_number) {
        
        let itemsToParse = this.items
        this.paginatedItems = itemsToParse.slice(page_number * page_size, (page_number + 1) * page_size);
        console.log(2)
        console.log(this.paginatedItems)
      },
      onPageChanged(page){
        console.log(3)
        this.paginate(this.perPage, page - 1)
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      console.log(1)
      this.paginate(this.perPage, 0)
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      },
      pageCount() {
        let l = this.totalRows,
          s = this.perPage;
        return Math.floor(l / s);
      }    
    },

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Perhaps this is something better asked on the repo's issue tracker? https://github.com/cdmoro/bootstrap-vue-3/issues

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly stated in the [docs](https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/getting-started/#why-bootstrapvue3) that: **NOT PRODUCTION READY: This project is still in alpha version. There is a lot of work to do**

There is even a [comparison with BootstrapVue (for Vue 2)](https://cdmoro.github.io/bootstrap-vue-3/reference/parityList.html#events-13) which clearly shows that `change` event of `Pagination` component is not implemented yet

This is of course something you should check before starting migration to Vue 3...